# Get a particular record based on a condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My requirement is to get id for missing status from **SQL table**. I will get a list of status for each id, say **A,B,C,D**. In a scenario, I have to check status **B** exists or not. Table gets updated everyday and each time new Id will be created

Conditions,

1. If status **A** exists and other statuses such as **C and D** does not
   exists, then don't need to get id.
2. If status **A** and **B** exists and other statuses such as **C or D** does not exists, then don't need to get id .
3. If status **A** exists and **B** not exists, other
   statuses such as **C or D** exists, then I should get the id of that
   record
4. If status **A** and **B** exists, other
   statuses such as **C or D** exists (all status exists), then I don't need to get the id of that
   record

```
    Table1:  
    Id StatusCode  
    1    A   
    1    C    
    2    A    
    2    B     
    2    C    
    3    A    
    3    C     
    3    D
```

How do I get Id 1 and 3 using SQL query?, Seems simple but as I am new to SQL I could not able to get it in SQL.

[image]

select statement in this screenshot works fine when there is only one id, it fails on multiple id. I tried many other way, but no use

Comment: can you give an example of the data?

Comment: case when expression

Comment: Do you need a single SQL statement which returns Id of Status A or Null? Or is it ok to implement this in multiple steps in a stored procedure?

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland I need to implement this in Store Procedure, So multiple steps also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID 
FROM T1
WHERE Statuscode = 'A' AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM T1 WHERE Statuscode = 'B' )
AND  (ID IN (SELECT ID FROM T1 WHERE Statuscode = 'C' ) OR ID IN (SELECT ID FROM T1 WHERE Statuscode = 'D' ))
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=73d0db1e7a5bd8e4f7d3172d519f1f80)**

Also, To correct [Gordon Linoff's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59530242/12550116) answer, we need to add one more where criteria there

```
SELECT Id
FROM T1
GROUP BY Id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Statuscode = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN Statuscode = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN Statuscode IN ('C', 'D') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8aa26146150b5e3927654cb945047380)**

Comment: Get null on this, have you executed this from your end?

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

I think you can use aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when status = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when status in ('C', 'D') then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Comment: @sp I don't understand why you can't use this. I mean it will give a correct result based on your question. The id has plays no role in the above query

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It works. It returns 1,2,3. But I need output as 1,3. As Id 2 has status **B**, it should not return it.

Comment: @sp . . . Your "mistake" was to change the question after it was answered.  It is better to ask a new question.  You have invalidated the answers of multiple people who tried to help, and that can attract downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct id from t where t.statuscode = 'C' or t.statuscode = 'D' group by t.id
```

Comment: This will be incorrect. For example it will return an Id that simply has a status code equals to C and may not have A

Comment: if statuscode =A is also required, add or t.statuscode = 'A' and so on, or if you don't care what value is statuscode, you can do  where t.statuscode is not null

Comment: you said such as, but you did not provide the full list, however, with this piece of code, you should be able to adapt it to every possible case

Comment: I am not the one who asked the question. Still this won't work without group by. See the answer by Gordon.

Comment: I have clearly updated my requirement conditions now. Your answer does not suits, thanks for your effort.

Comment: you get the idea, with the new requirements, you just need to consider every case, and it will work, but it is probably something that can be done in less lines of SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
FROM t
GROUP BY
    Id
HAVING MAX(status) = CHAR(64 + COUNT(*))
--char(64+1) = A, char(64+2) = B etc
```

The logic behind this is that it will take all count the same types of id. So if you have 3 rows you will need abc. If you have an id with 4 rows you will have ABCD. Generally the max status should always be the same as the number of rows.

This is true of course if you have no duplicate between id and status code.